# Token classification errors when used offline

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I have downloaded a [huggingsface model](https://huggingface.co/kinit/slovakbert-pos) but results of my script that runs locally are different than what is produced on the model web page.

Example:

When I use the word "drieme" as an example on the web page and hit the "Compute" button, I get 1 token (which is correct).
When I run the following script (with the same word "drieme" ) I get 2 tokens.

```
from transformers import pipeline

nlp = pipeline("token-classification", model="C:\slovakbert-pos", tokenizer="C:\slovakbert-pos")

sequence = "drieme"

result = nlp(sequence)

for r in result:
    print(r)
```

Results:

```
{'entity': 'VERB', 'score': 0.9986156, 'index': 1, 'word': 'd', 'start': 0, 'end': 1}
{'entity': 'VERB', 'score': 0.99858165, 'index': 2, 'word': 'rieme', 'start': 1, 'end': 6}
```

This problem can be reproduced using many words or sentences.

Many thanks for any kind of advise.

I wanted to reproduce the behaviour from the model web page